# How to return a reactive variable from a setup() function?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am building a small notes app and learning Vue3 + Typescript on the way. The code below allows to dynamically create and display an Array of notes (I hope I trimmed it down correctly, a general description is below the code):

```
<template>
  <q-layout>
    <div
        v-for="note in allNotes"
        class="note q-ma-sm q-gutter-sm"
        :id="note.id"
    >
      <q-editor
          v-model="note.text"
      >
      </q-editor>
    </div>

    <q-page-sticky position="bottom-right" :offset="[18, 18]">
      <q-btn fab icon="add" color="accent" @click="addNewNote"/>
    </q-page-sticky>
  </q-layout>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, ref} from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  components: {},
  setup() {

    // a single note
    interface Note {
      id: number
      creationDate: string
      text: string
      tags: string[]
      deleted: boolean
      isFocused: boolean
    }

    // all the notes in the app
    let allNotes = ref<Note[]>([])

    function addNewNote() {
      const now = new Date()
      allNotes.value.push({
        creationDate: now.toISOString(),
        deleted: false,
        id: now.getTime(),
        tags: [],
        text: "",
        isFocused: false
      })
    }

    function displayedNotes() {
      return allNotes
    }

    return {
      allNotes,
      addNewNote,
    }
  }
});
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

The idea is that `allNotes` holds the notes, which are displayed in a `v-for` loop.

I wanted to make a small modification, in anticipation that the notes to be displayed will be filtered, to this I created a method `displayedNotes` that is supposed to simply return `allNotes` (later there will be some filtering happening there)

```
<template>
  <q-layout>
    <div
        v-for="note in displayedNotes"
        class="note q-ma-sm q-gutter-sm"
        :id="note.id"
    >
      <q-editor
          v-model="note.text"
      >
      </q-editor>
    </div>

    <q-page-sticky position="bottom-right" :offset="[18, 18]">
      <q-btn fab icon="add" color="accent" @click="addNewNote"/>
    </q-page-sticky>
  </q-layout>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, ref} from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  components: {},
  setup() {

    // a single note
    interface Note {
      id: number
      creationDate: string
      text: string
      tags: string[]
      deleted: boolean
      isFocused: boolean
    }

    // all the notes in the app
    let allNotes = ref<Note[]>([])

    function addNewNote() {
      const now = new Date()
      allNotes.value.push({
        creationDate: now.toISOString(),
        deleted: false,
        id: now.getTime(),
        tags: [],
        text: "",
        isFocused: false
      })
    }

    function displayedNotes() {
      return allNotes
    }

    return {
      allNotes,
      displayedNotes,
      addNewNote,
    }
  }
});
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

The differences are

- `v-for` iterates over `displayedNotes` and not `allNotes` anymore
- `displayedNotes()` is a new method.

The end result is that nothing is displayed, `displayedNotes` is created but is empty when `allNotes` grow.

**How should I return `displayedNotes` so that it is reactive?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a computed property like this:

```
const filteredNotes = computed(() => displayedNotes())
```

In that case `displayedNotes()` might be renamed later on, and in that function you can add your filtering logic. If your `allNotes` then changes, that function within computed will be called again and will return the new `filteredNotes`

What you want to do now is only add `filteredNotes` to your return object, and use it in your `v-for` loop instead of `allNotes`

Comment: Also to understand what isn't working correctly in your code. There are probably 2 things
1. in your `v-for` call you need to call `displayedNotes()` I guess. 
2. you are returning `allNotes` which is a `ref`. so what you actually have there is a `Proxy` and you are only returning that one. You would need to add `.value` to your `return allNotes`

Comment: Thank you. First, I forgot about `computed()` :/. Thans for reminding me. Then I realized that I do not understand much about the `.value` part (I know about it, just not too sure where it is should really be used) - I will read on that. And finally with the changes, everything works :) Thanks